# Forward a UIGestureRecognizer from one view controller to another view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, first-responder

I'm adding a `UIGestureRecognizer` to one of my view controllers `view`.

My desired behaviour is when this gesture is recognised to dismiss the gestures view controller and forward it to another view controller. (the view controller I want to forward it has presented the view controller with the gesture)

Right now when I dismiss the view controller, the pinch gesture recogniser is (logically) failing.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirements in detail

Comment: View controllers do not respond to gesture recognizers, views do. I would update your question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

\EDIT: Now the delegate get the argument with the gestureRecognizer.

You can just implement protocol like:

```
@protocol ViewControllerWithGestureRecognizerDelegate

- (void)viewControllerGestureRecognizerEvent:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;

@end
```

and add the delegate property to the view controller in which there will be presented gesture recognizer.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ViewControllerWithGestureRecognizerDelegate> delegate;
```

Then add the gesture recognizer to your view Controller:

```
 UIPinchGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureRecognizerAction:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

Call the delegate method in action method of the gesture recognizer:

```
 - (void)gestureRecognizerAction:(UIPichGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
 {
   [self.delegate viewControllerGestureRecognizerEvent:gestureRecognizer];
 }
```

Implement the protocol ViewControllerWithGestureRecognizerDelegate in the second view controller (in which you want to get notified about gesture recognizer events) and set the delegate of the view controller which gesture recognizer to be the second view controller.

```
 ViewControllerWithGestureRecognizer.delegate = ViewControllerInWhichYouWantToGetNotifiedAboutGestureRecognizerEvents.
```

This way every time the gesture recognizer will call method on the the one view controller, the second one will be informed about that.

Comment: Thanks, but my gesture is continuous (UIPinchGestureRecognizer) so I want to forward the whole gesture instead of simply calling a method.

Comment: I edited my answer so that second controller can have access to your gestureRecognizer.

Comment: why not simply set the gestureRecognizer's delegate property to the other view controller, and make the otherVC conform to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol? e.g gestureRecognizer.delegate = otherVC;

Comment: Thanks, but the problem here is when this pinch gesture is recognised I dismiss the view controller, so the pinch fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `delaysTouchesEnded` until the gesture is recognized:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL delaysTouchesEnded
```

Answer (score 0):

Will implementing this delegate method not solve your problem?

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```